# How to find the occurrence of a cell in a sequence (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with names.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Names":['Bob','Rob','John','Bob','Jacob']})
```

I want to increment the occurrence number by 1 if the name is repeated. How to do that in pandas?

I want the output like below

```
   Names  Occurance
0    Bob          1
1    Rob          1
2   John          1
3    Bob          2
4  Jacob          1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and add `1`:

```
df['Occurance'] = df.groupby('Names').cumcount() + 1
print (df)
   Names  Occurance
0    Bob          1
1    Rob          1
2   John          1
3    Bob          2
4  Jacob          1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did try `cumcount()` but misspelled the column name. My bad